# Windows 11 does not contain a toggle to disable touchpad

Tags: windows, touchpad, windows-11

I've installed Windows 11 and I want to disable my touchpad. According to other sources, there should be a Toggle in the settings for the touchpad. However, my touchpad settings contains no such thing:

[image]

How do I disable the touchpad?

I'm aware of Device Manager but it's not clear which is the touchpad driver.

EDIT:

My Device Manager:

[image]

Comment: Many devices that don't have drivers installed. I bet one is your motherboard chipset driver and as a result it may detect your touchpad as ps/2 compatible mouse, or its as unknown device. Install all drivers with yellow exclaimation mark, and all will start working normally.

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

- Run Device Manager
- Open "Mouse and other pointing devices"
- The touchpad might be called "HID-compliant mouse"
- Right-click it and select "Disable device".

Comment: Unfortunately not. I just pasted my Device Manager above. Reckon it's because i'm missing a driver? I did run Lenovo System Update but it found nothing to install.

Comment: Perhaps you're missing a driver. Do you know the exact model of the touchpad? If you can't find that, what is the model of the computer?

Comment: It's an x230 Thinkpad

Comment: Go to [Lenovo Drivers & Software](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/fr/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x230/downloads/automatic-driver-update) and run the "Automatic Driver Update".

Comment: Checking.......

Comment: Unfortunately says nothing to find. I thought this might be the case because i installed Lenovo System Update and it said same thing.

Comment: How old is this laptop?

Comment: 2013. Windows 10 finds all the drivers though

Comment: Has it worked in Windows 10?

Comment: Yeah managed to get all the drivers and disable the touchpad

Answer (score 0):

Your touch pad can be found under **Human Interface Devices**.

[image]

Keep in mind that you will have to open the device manager as and administrator in order to make changes. You can do this by starting `devmgmt.msc` and selecting `Run as Administrator`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have "Human Interface Devices" in the list

Comment: Might be one of the unknown devices then. You can try finding/installing drivers for these from the device manager, that will usually also give them more descriptive names in the devmgmt overview.

Answer (score 0):

- If your touchpad has an OEM control panel, e.g., [Elan's CPL](https://photo-cms-viettimes.zadn.vn/Uploaded/2021/nsxrureyxq/2016_11_15/1593578_xarf.jpg), disable it there. Some manufacturer's even have a setting to disable the touchpad automatically when an external pointing device, such as a mouse or drawing tablet, is active. You might be able to install the CPL from the touchpad manufacturer's site.
- In *Device manager*, under *Mice and other pointing devices,* select the touchpad, right-click and *Disable*.

[image: Disable Touchpad in Device Mgr]

- Using the Windows *Registry*:

  - Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `rege` and select *Regedit*.
  - Accept the UAC dialog to allow *Regedit* to run.
  - Open the following key, either by copy-and-paste into the location bar, or by scrolling:
    `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PrecisionTouchPad\Status`
  - Double-click value *Enabled* and set it to number 0.

[image: Disable Touchpad in Registry]

That value can be saved from *Regedit* as a .reg file, both with and without the touchpad enabled, giving you two files (e.g., *TPadOn.reg* and *TPadOff.reg*) to use to set the touchpad *On* or *Off* at will. Just double-click a .reg file and accept the warning about allowing changes.

Comment: No idea how to explain this.... but i've done the registry edit but it's still working! (I'm pretty computer literate, so not a complete n00b). My laptop is fairly old, circa 2013. But seems Windows isn't use that reg key??

Comment: Have you rebooted? Not using "quick start" or from hibernate, but using **shutdown /s /f /t 0**, which will abruptly terminate *all** processes and shut down. Then use power button to start up again. That can be copied and pasted into the Run (Win+R) line or into CMD.

Comment: I used an actual restart